# Faking throttle position using injector output

Tags: voltage, circuit-design, pwm, voltage-divider

Car guy in need of electrical insight.

Long story short I am running standalone engine management in parallel with the stock ecu, I need to fake a throttle body position sensor voltage.

My plan is to use a spare injector output to control some sort of circuit that will vary between 0.6 - 4.75v. This output is either floating or ground, I can adjust duty cycle 0-100% and frequency 1-10k hz.

The stock throttle body plug has a 5v, Gnd, TPS1, and TPS2.

[image]

I have tried an RC circuit with a 5k resistor and 2.2uf cap in series with the PWM out grounding the connection between the two, but only saw .52v at the connection when varying the duty cycle.

Any insight or suggestions are welcome

Comment: The circuit you tried instantly removes any charge on the capacitor when the PWM goes low. Try adding a 680 ohm resistor between the PWM output and the node where the 5K resistor and 2.2uF meet. Response won't be anywhere close to linear - more complicated circuit is needed if you require it to be linear.

Comment: Why fake it? Just pump in the real TPS measurement, I'm sure the standalone uses the TPS as well, and there's a good chance the two together will not overload that signal. If it is overloaded you could buffer it with a rail to rail opamp or just slap a second TPS on if you're handy.

Comment: As you have the engine on a rig, why not just use the stock Throttle Position Sensor and use that to control the throttle setting. Could have it spring loaded and lockable etc.